# How to direct message everyone in a guild? Discord.Net

Tags: discord.net

I am making a discord bot that DMS everyone in a guild for like announcements but i do not know how i would do that. I know how to send it to a specified user but not all users in a guild.

Please help me out.

Comment: This is not only a terrible idea, but also a potential violation against Discord's API ToS, as this is a spammy behavior.

Comment: @Still It is meant for some small discord server (100 members) so they can announce it via direct messages. I do not have any bad meanings or plans to abuse this.

Comment: Regardless of the intention or size, it is still a very bad idea. There are better ways around this, such as a registering everyone in the guild with a role, and then ping the said role in a text channel.

Answer (score 1):

You loop through each users in `Guild.Users`.
Maybe run a `Guild.DownloadUsersAsync();` just before it to ensure you have all users.

```
await Context.Guild.DownloadUsersAsync(); //make sure we have each guild user 
foreach (var user in Context.Guild.Users)
{
    try
    {
        var channel = await user.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync();
        await channel.SendMessageAsync("what's up");
    }
    catch { } //catch an error, such as the user having disabled DMs
}
```

Comment: This is assuming that they are doing this under the context of a command module. Catch should also be more explicit; the exception for when DM is disabled is documented [here](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.IUser.html#Discord_IUser_GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync_Discord_RequestOptions_).

Comment: Yeah I know both of those things. He didn't give much to go on, so I thought I'd just assume he's probably on a command context example he's downloaded from somewhere. If not, seems like he at least knows how to get around it. And the try-catch was just there just to let him know that it's good to use so it doesn't crash when a user isn't accepting dms.